# Is it okay to ask for death penalty of a murderer?

Tags: allah

One police officer killed many innocent man and he is extremely corrupt. Recently he got arrested for his deeds. If he proves guilty then he will get death penalty. But during prayer I asked for his punishment as a death penalty. But somehow I felt guilty for asking someone's death. Is it okay for me to ask? If I did anything wrong then how can I ask forgiveness?

Answer (score -1):

The Prophet himself (saws) has asked for death penalty, so it cannot be a sin. However, he (saws) also showed mercy when it came to the judgement, so those people who say sharia law is always to opt for the maximum penalty are in error, too.
Death penalty has four major drawbacks:
Nobody can make a person alive if it comes out that the person was not guilty.
It is very often abused by injust governments and systems.
Mankind tends to become rude when death penalty is applied because those full of hatred become loud.
The sinner, if he is, is deprived of any chance to repentance.
In this sense, your prayer is not a sin but your doubts whether this kind of prayer is good, has a good reason, too.

Comment: Qisas is obligatory when the heirs decide to not forgive. It can not be forgiven by anyone other than the heirs of the victim.

Comment: @UmH You are right that Qisas is part of Islamic law. It is fixed in Quran 2:178, confirming the law of Mose Exodus 21:23. You can read there that this is a relief and an expression of mercy from Allah. This is said so because the maximum punishment in former Arabic law even allowed a punishment more severe than the deed. Asr

Comment: Having a closer look on the deeds of the Prophet (saws) I saw that this may have been under martial law not under Qisas. However, the subject of the question was essentially whether it is good to plead for punishment. Jesus quite clearly advised his disciples to forgive and not plead for the maximum punishment. He was not in charge of a state ruler but Muhammad (saws) was, so he had to decide about the ideals and applicable law at the same. I am telling what I have understood, that is that there is a right to claim punishment but it is not the ideal to make use of it.